# Make 2 elements exactly below each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following html code. Currently the label and textarea are in the same **row** I am trying to put the submit button exactly below the left corner of `textarea`, but it seems that my idea does not work:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="comments" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Comments</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <textarea id="summernote" th:field="*{comments}" class="summernote ">          
        </textarea>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group col-sm-6" style="float: right;">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="float: left;">
        <input type="submit"  value="Submit The Feedback" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
   </div>
```

How should i fix it?

I am using bootstrap

Comment: "I am trying to put the submit button exactly below the left corner of textarea" then why using this style="float: right;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comments" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Comments</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <textarea id="summernote" th:field="*{comments}" class="summernote "></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9" style="float: left;">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit The Feedback" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the style `float: right;` for the outer div(`form-group col-sm-6`) with the button and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `col-sm-3` for `comments label` you should remove the `float` and set the offset of `col-sm-offset-3`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comments" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Comments</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <textarea id="summernote" th:field="*{comments}" class="summernote "></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="float: left;">
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit The Feedback" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/33CoKCh2Ax) to test your code and snapshot:

[image]

Further [check this out](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) to better understand the grid structure with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were trying to do, just remove the styles and put the button after the textarea:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comments" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Comments</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <textarea id="summernote" th:field="*{comments}" class="summernote ">
    </textarea>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit The Feedback" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad, currently the label and text area are in the same **row**

Answer (score 0):

Go with below link or just try below code may be it can help you -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn6f4gq1/3/)

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comments" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Comments</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <textarea id="summernote" th:field="*{comments}" class="summernote ">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit The Feedback" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```